# p12 file not connected to distribution cert

Tags: ios, key, pkcs#12

I had an app developed for me and I am finishing it up by myself.  I have received all the certs and things and have dev cert attached to private key but not the distribution cert.  when clicking my provisioning profile for distribution I get the message:

> "valid signing identity not found"

I was able to attach my other cert to the p12 file through terminal but I cannot find that info again.  I have the two files but they are not connected.  Does anyone know how to do this in terminal?  can it be done?  I am getting errors regarding:

> "Failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iphon distribution certificate."

and noticed my distribution cert has no key attached.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the certificate to be in a `p12` to make Xcode use it. It needs to be in your Keychain. Double click the certificate and it should end up being "installed" into your Keychain. And don't worry about the `p12`, that's a red herring.